# Make computer give the choice to boot from my partitions

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I  have a new computer that came with windows 8.1.

I installed ubuntu 15.04 on another partition, so that I had the choice to boot from either windows or ubuntu when the computer starts up.
But there was a hardware failure in my computer, which means I had to send it in where I bought it. They fixed the hardware failure. But now when I start my computer, it only boots in windows, not giving me the chance to boot from ubunty. At first, I thought they deleted ubuntu, but when I wanted to install ubuntu again from usb, I can see that my ubuntu 15.04 is still there with all its data.

How do I make it so that I can choose to boot from windows and ubuntu again?

I am fairly new to linux

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to restore the GRUB bootloader. [This is official wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) on the problem.